# SQL Select every 10 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with a column called "`dateadded`" and every day I have to run a query to get each row that is completing 8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58 etc. months old.

That's the way I do today:

```
select * from table 
where DATEADD(month, DATEADDED , 8) = GETDATE() 
or DATEADD(month, DATEADDED , 18) = GETDATE() 
or DATEADD(month, DATEADDED , 28) = GETDATE()  ...
```

But I don't want to use 100 "`or`" or more. 
Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: So you want all rows where dateadded fell sometime on the same day as today but 8 months ago, 18 months ago, etc.? Back how far? What is the earliest date in your table?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it should be `DATEADD(datepart,number,date)`

Comment: I have to use the earlier date of the table to know back how far (which is today 1999-02-01, but it can change).

Comment: Someone's going to later add a row to this table, and DATEADDED will become some date earlier than 1992?

Comment: yep, because not every record is ported from the old database yet.

Comment: Ok, so what's the oldest date in the old database?

Comment: This 1999-02-01 is the oldest, just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM        table 
WHERE       DATEDIFF(month, DATEADDED , GETDATE()) % 10 = 8
    AND     DATEDIFF(month, DATEADDED , GETDATE()) < 100 -- ignore more than 100 months old
```

And use the `DATEDIFF()` function to give you your month offsets, feed that in to a modulo operator to find the acceptable offsets.

Comment: @Antonio they are for *you*, but they might not be for another reader trying to solve the same problem, so it's important to point it out. Same with the part about sargability - this won't use an index on DATEADDED, if one exists.

Answer (score 5):

This can make use of an index on the `DATEADDED` column, should one exist, or should one be added in the future. Solutions that perform functions like `DATEDIFF()` against the column directly prevent SQL Server from even considering the index, and will force it to scan instead (lacking any other predicates to limit the search space).

```
CREATE TABLE #x(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), DATEADDED DATETIME);

INSERT #x(DATEADDED) VALUES
('20130605 04:56'), -- 8 months ago
('20120805 23:59'), -- 18 months ago
('20111005 14:36'), -- 28 months ago
('20101105 04:23'); -- should not be found

;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH,'19990201',GETDATE())/10+1) 
    d = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,-((number*10)-2),GETDATE()))
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE [type] = N'P' AND number > 0 ORDER BY number
)
SELECT x.ID, x.DATEADDED
FROM #x AS x
 INNER JOIN cte
 ON x.DATEADDED >= cte.d
 AND x.DATEADDED < DATEADD(DAY,1,cte.d);
```